# CakePHP redirecting to /users/login

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've recently copied my webpage from one server to another. Full webserver root directory download and extracted the MySQL database. I've set it over, and it works fine, however, it redirects me to `webpage.com/users/login`. This is what it's supposed to do but it shows me a 404 and when I look in the root directory, there is no users or a login file.

On the old website root directory there is also no users or a login folder but the website does work. Can anyone explain this to me? How is this possible?

The Apache error log shows:

```
[Fri Jan 01 22:26:30 2016] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] File does not exist: /var/www/html/users
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was missing the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        #Rewrite CakePHP
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !server-status
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```